# xpath locator not work as expected to locate a "<a" element with compound class name

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver

This line will not work but I think I have used correct xpath?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'cke_button_bold')]")).click();
```

to locate a button like below :

```
<a id="cke_73" class="cke_off cke_button_bold">
```

id is a dynamic number so can be used as fixed locator here. And class is a compound class which is not supported by WebDriver findElement method...

Comment: Sorry I should attach all content of the target element.  it do have a href attribute  <a id="cke_73" class="cke_button_bold cke_off" href="javascript:void('Bold')" title="Bold" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" onblur="this.style.cssText = this.style.cssText;" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.ui.button._.keydown(52, event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.ui.button._.focus(52, event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(61, this); return false;">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created simple html file and your xpath works with FirefoxDriver in WebDriver 2.1.0.
Also you can try to use

```
driver.findElement(By.className("cke_button_bold"))
```

Classname is supported by [webdriver Api](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

Find the CSS Selector

Possible CSS Selectors here:

css=a[id*='cke']

css=.cke_off cke_button_bold

The above can be used Or Already we are having the method .ClassName But for avoiding duplication of Elements and Ambiguity we can use CSS Selector.